# ValueError: 'balanced_accuracy' is not a valid scoring value in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

I tried to pass to `GridSearchCV` other scoring metrics like `balanced_accuracy` for Binary Classification (instead of the default `accuracy`)

```
  scoring = ['balanced_accuracy','recall','roc_auc','f1','precision']
  validator = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scoring, refit=refit_scorer, cv=cv)
```

and got this error

> ValueError: 'balanced_accuracy' is not a valid scoring value. Valid
>   options are
>   ['accuracy','adjusted_mutual_info_score','adjusted_rand_score','average_precision','completeness_score','explained_variance','f1','f1_macro','f1_micro','f1_samples','f1_weighted','fowlkes_mallows_score','homogeneity_score','mutual_info_score','neg_log_loss','neg_mean_absolute_error','neg_mean_squared_error','neg_mean_squared_log_error','neg_median_absolute_error','normalized_mutual_info_score','precision','precision_macro','precision_micro','precision_samples','precision_weighted','r2','recall','recall_macro','recall_micro','recall_samples','recall_weighted','roc_auc','v_measure_score']

This is strange because 'balanced_accuracy' [should be valid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) 
Without defining `balanced_accuracy` then the code works fine

```
    scoring = ['recall','roc_auc','f1','precision']
```

Also the scoring metrics in the error above seems to be different from the ones in the [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values)

Any ideas why? Thank you so much

`scikit-learn` version is 0.19.2

Comment: Please post the relevant code - as it is, there are not enough details for the question to be answered meaningfully. Also post your scikit-learn version (you can get it with `sklearn.__version__)`)

Comment: Thank you I added the code and `scikit-learn` version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your sklearn to the latest version if you want to use `balanced_accuracy`. As you can see from the [0.19 documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) `balanced_accuracy` is not a valid scoring metric. It was [added in 0.20](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.20.html#id33).

Comment: First I taugh, what a nice solution, but somehow it is not working, where is my mistake? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377154/balanced-accuracy-is-not-a-valid-scoring-value-in-scikit-learn