# Balanced_accuracy is not a valid scoring value in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

super simliar to this post: [ValueError: 'balanced_accuracy' is not a valid scoring value in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349331/valueerror-balanced-accuracy-is-not-a-valid-scoring-value-in-scikit-learn/53352437)

I am using:

```
scoring = ['precision_macro', 'recall_macro', 'balanced_accuracy_score']
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=10, return_train_score=True)
```

And i receive the error:

> ValueError: 'balanced_accuracy_score' is not a valid scoring value.
>   Use sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()) to get valid options.

I did the recommended solution and upgraded scikit (in the enviornment):
[image]

When I check the possible scorers:

```
sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()
dict_keys(['explained_variance', 'r2', 'max_error', 'neg_median_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_squared_log_error', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_poisson_deviance', 'neg_mean_gamma_deviance', 'accuracy', 'roc_auc', 'roc_auc_ovr', 'roc_auc_ovo', 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted', 'roc_auc_ovo_weighted', 'balanced_accuracy', 'average_precision', 'neg_log_loss', 'neg_brier_score', 'adjusted_rand_score', 'homogeneity_score', 'completeness_score', 'v_measure_score', 'mutual_info_score', 'adjusted_mutual_info_score', 'normalized_mutual_info_score', 'fowlkes_mallows_score', 'precision', 'precision_macro', 'precision_micro', 'precision_samples', 'precision_weighted', 'recall', 'recall_macro', 'recall_micro', 'recall_samples', 'recall_weighted', 'f1', 'f1_macro', 'f1_micro', 'f1_samples', 'f1_weighted', 'jaccard', 'jaccard_macro', 'jaccard_micro', 'jaccard_samples', 'jaccard_weighted'])
```

I can stil not find it? Where is the problem?

Comment: perhaps your code is still relying on an old version? try printing the version of sklearn

Comment: what is the command to print it in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs for valid scorers](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values), the value of the `scoring` parameter corresponding to the [`balanced_accuracy_score` scorer function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score) is `"balanced_accuracy"` as in my other answer:

Change:

```
scoring = ['precision_macro', 'recall_macro', 'balanced_accuracy_score']
```

to:

```
scoring = ['precision_macro', 'recall_macro', 'balanced_accuracy']
```

and it should work.

I do find the documentation a bit lacking in this respect, and this convention of removing the `_score` suffix is not consistent either, as all the clustering metrics still have `_score` in their names in their `scoring` parameter values.